# Problem with DT table update in shiny and extract table contents as R objects

Tags: r, shiny, dt

Im trying to follow the examples (https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/) for editing a DT table in R shiny, but cannot seem to get it to update correctly. Below is a toy example. As a test, table edits should print to the main panel when hitting "go," but the edits are not passed along. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Second, I would like to be able to work with the table as an R object that I can pass along to other aspects of the code (e.g., pass one of the columns as a vector to something else). But I am not 100% sure how to do this. Ideally this might be something like "hot_to_r" in the rhandsontable package, but I am not sure how this might be done for DT. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("use DT package"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

  h4('A Table Using Server-side Processing'),
  fluidRow(
    column(2),
    column(8, DT::dataTableOutput('tb')),
    column(2)
  ), 

  actionButton("go", "go")
  ),

  mainPanel(
  verbatimTextOutput("test"), #to test if the table updates

  )))

server <- (function(input, output, session) {

  DF <- data.frame(Original_Name = rep("place holder", 3), New_Name = rep("place holder", 3), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$tb <- renderDT(DF, selection = "none", server = TRUE, editable = "all")

  # update edited cells ("all")
  observeEvent(input$tb_cell_edit, {
    DF <<- editData(DF, input$tb_cell_edit, 'tb')
  })

  #print the table to test that it works
  #but what I really want is to create an R object that I can use 
  #to extract column "Original_Name" and "New_Name"
  observeEvent(input$go,{
  output$test<-renderPrint(DF)
  })

})

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server), launch.browser=TRUE) #launch in browser
```

Comment: Is the data.frame going to be the result of a file or any other sort of input, or is it just going to be from a file stored locally?

Comment: I am using the two columns of the table (old_name, new_name) to create a recode vector in the cars package. I had have already implemented this using the rhandsontable package, but rhandsontable has some indexing instablity that causes it to crash occasionally (See https://github.com/jrowen/rhandsontable/issues/112). And I like the look of the DT table better anyway :)

Comment: Using the rhandsontable , the recode vector works like this (again, for cars package):

values<-reactiveValues()
        values$recodeDF <- hot_to_r( input$recodeTable ) #convert to R object 
        
        op <- options("useFancyQuotes") #turn of fancy quotes
        reccodeVector<-paste(sQuote(values$recodeDF$Original_Name), sQuote(values$recodeDF$New_Name), sep = "=", collapse = "; ") # make recode vector from dataFrame
        options(useFancyQuotes = FALSE)# turn off fancy quotes

Comment: @rpolicastro, I think I misunderstood your question earlier (see my comments above). The data.frame is user input in the app. That is, the user will enter old and new names that I will reformat as a recode vector using the cars package. So, no, the data.frame is not the result of a file. Initially it is just a simple data.frame stored locally as shown in the example. Thank you.

Comment: Once the row is modified, click Ctrl + Enter to save the row. Otherwise your code words.